# How to fetch API from swagger file using kong gateway

Tags: json, docker, kong, kong-plugin, konga

I have create a service, a route, an auth, a consumer, a username and a password in the kong admin UI through curl command.  Below there is the command that I have used and it's showing in the kong admin UI.

I have installed Kong as docker container with image version is kong/kong-gateway:2.8.1.2-alpine

```
curl -X POST http://x.x.x.x:8001/services \
  --data name=admin-api \
  --data host=x.x.x.x \
  --data port=8001
  
curl -X POST http://x.x.x.x:8001/services/admin-api/routes \
  --data paths\[\]=/admin-api
  
curl -X POST http://x.x.x.x:8001/services/admin-api/plugins \
        --data "name=basic-auth"  \
        --data "config.hide_credentials=true"  
       
curl -d "username=first-consumer&custom_id=1" http://x.x.x.x:8001/consumers/

curl -X POST http://x.x.x.x:8001/consumers/first-consumer/basic-auth \
    --data "username=first-consumer" \
    --data "password=my-password"

curl -s -X GET \
  --url http://x.x.x.x:8000/admin-api \
  --header 'Authorization: Basic Zmlyc3QtY29uc3VtZXI6bXktcGFzc3dvcmQK'
```

Below command I get 200 ok response

```
curl -i -X GET --url http://20.69.125.27:8000 --header "Host: petstore.swagger.io" --header "apikey: apisec"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 734
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Wed, 10 Aug 2022 11:52:06 GMT
Server: nginx
Last-Modified: Tue, 02 Aug 2022 12:23:11 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
ETag: "62e9172f-2de"
Expires: Thu, 11 Aug 2022 11:52:06 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Kong-Upstream-Latency: 322
X-Kong-Proxy-Latency: 52
Via: kong/2.8.1.2-enterprise-edition

<!-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Swagger UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./swagger-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="swagger-ui"></div>
    <script src="./swagger-ui-bundle.js" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
    <script src="./swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
    <script src="./swagger-initializer.js" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

im getting above output in html but i want in json format

How to get fetch on https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json through curl as json file from kong setup ?

Comment: What have you tried and what error do you get ?

Comment: I'm trying to fetch petstore swagger json file through kong and i have update my question plse read it once